# How can I add ITF reader to my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, barcode-scanner

I'm interested in developing an app for iPhone that can scan and read ITF codes, like on tags of clothes.

I would like to know if there is an SDK I could use?

Should I contact the retailers for recieving the ITF bar codes?

How should I insert those ITF barcodes to my app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). The lousy camera of early iPhone models might get in the way...

Comment: Thanks. Should I contact the retailers to sent me the ITF bar codes?
How should I insert those ITF barcodes to my app?

Comment: I have no idea what's the supposed business model of your app. ZXing is the SDK for scanning and reading codes; how to interpret them is up to you.

Comment: i would be glad if you could explain what do you mean by read the code. this is the part i don't understand.. itf has a number (14 digits) underneath the code so why do i need the code? should i create a db for the number - link. does zxing supports this?

Comment: You said: "I'm interested in developing an app for iPhone that can scan and read ITF codes". What did *you* mean by "read"?

Comment: i ment that after scanning an itf code i'd like my app to show an image of the item or direct to a link. i would like to use this for retailers that already use itf codes for their products.

Comment: The content of a barcode is typically a relatively short short number - an index into the retailer's corporate database. Without active cooperation from the retailer (like letting you access the database), you can't figure out what this is.